# Error: queryTxt ETIMEOUT when connecting to MongoDb Atlas using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Im trying to connect my mongoose with my MongoDB Atlas Cluster. It currently has no database or anything but whenever I try:

```
mongoose.connect( uri || 'mongodb://localhost/test',options)
.then(()=>{
    console.log("Connected to the Database. Yayzow!");
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

I get this message:

```
Error: queryTxt ETIMEOUT cluster0-ghis2.mongodb.net
at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:202:19) {
errno: 'ETIMEOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEOUT',
  syscall: 'queryTxt',
  hostname: 'cluster0-ghis2.mongodb.net'
}
```

My dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.5.7",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.14"
  }
```

I've whitelisted all IPs as off now (0.0.0.0/0). Also I've made sure my firewall is disconnected and so is my anti-virus. I made my friend check it out too and it did work for him but not me

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT**

Solved the error by changing my DNS to Google's Public DNS!
If anyone get this error just make sure to change your DNS.
Throwing a link for the same [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F9u5ULrRt3Y)

Comment: Two things: 1. Today (14/05/2020) MongoDb Atlas has been extremely slow (at least for me). As I write this I can barely access the website, so maybe it's not just you and it's a connection problem. 2. Once I had a similar problem after I whitelisted all IPs, so I also whitelisted my actual IP (ex: 192.xxx.xxx...) and solved my problem, so try doing that.

Comment: Even i thought that it'd be their problem but then i gave my friends my credentials and it worked for him. I'll try the second one and let you know. Appreciate your help by the way

Comment: Thanks but turned out it was my net issue. Solved it by changing the DNS as mentioned in the EDIT section of my question.

Comment: Its wokring for me in localhost but when I deploy my app to Heroku and run it I get  error "Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms". have whitelisted all ip for cluster

Comment: Thanks for adding edit for DNS setting, it worked for me!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Changing DNS to 8.8.8.8 works for me.

Before changing my DNS, I tried to reinstall mongoose, check my connection, and turn off my vpn. None of them worked.

Comment: This solution is included in an edit in the question.

Comment: you saved my day

Comment: This worked by changing IPV4 DNS to 8.8.8.8 and reconnected to Internet.

Comment: Can't believe it, this worked! On Mac: Network Settings > Wifi > Advanced > DNS > 8.8.8.8

Answer (score 46):

The error because of the version of you node and npm,
to remove this error you just need to change you connection String by going to Connect and connect to Application

1. change the version to **2.2.122 or later**
2. copy String and paste then try to connect it again.
   as shown in Picture
   [image]

Comment: But the question is why? @Bilal

Comment: @wiki this sometimes occurs because of lower node and npm versions

Comment: why this happens

Comment: @Rahul as i mentioned above this occurs because of lower version of node installed on your system

Answer (score 14):

You need to add `&ssl=true` in your url, and your complete url should look like this

```
mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@********.mongodb.net/<db name>?authSource=admin&compressors=zlib&retryWrites=true&w=majority&ssl=true
```

Comment: Wow that was it. Why in the world. Thank you!

Comment: ssl shouldn't be true, as tls will be false. "Use of the +srv connection string modifier automatically sets the tls (or the equivalent ssl) option to true for the connection. " [Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/)

Answer (score 11):

to solve this issue make sure to choose older version of node (2.2.12) or later

[image]

and then make sure to add your ip address whitelisted

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Only switching from my mobile hotspot to fiber connection worked. I have no clue how that happened , it solved the issue. (P.S. I had whitelisted my IP when connected to mobile hotspot, so this reasoning is eliminated)

Comment: This solution works for me, I switch my connection from mobile data to WiFi and everything magically works. Does anyone know what the reason of this?

Comment: ironically, that worked :(

Comment: is there any way to make the monogodb connection work with WIFI?

Comment: same, i use mobile hotspot and it goes to timeout everytime, i switch to my home wifi it worked,

i try with hotspot again and change DNS to 1.1.1.1
it worked....

i assume the ISP blocked the domain or smth related...

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that several of these answers really come down to the same thing - the network needs to be reset.  I just had an odd experience - I had to different apps running on different ports but both accessing the same mongo instance.  One had the connection error, the other did not.  I rebooted and both were fine going forward.

The other scenario that caused this is an instance where I did not have an async / await around the mongoose call.

Comment: What do you mean by "the network has to be reset"?

Answer (score 1):

I turned my wi-fi off and on again and it worked

Comment: Same, dude, same!

Answer (score 0):

try to change your dns to google dns :

For windows:

1. go to control panel
2. search for `network and sharing center`
3. click on your internet or wifi
4. select properties
5. search for `internet protocol version 4(TCP/IPv4)`
6. enter this to the fields :

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Please check your connection string. The password must be a encoded one not as a plain text.

Answer (score -1):

In my case problem was in Database Network Access. I should choose my current IP address instead of ALLOW ACCESS FROM ANYWHERE

Answer (score -1):

Just off my mobile data connection, on it, and connect the hotspot again. It's started working.

Answer (score -2):

Ensure your Connection URL is ok. In .env file(one for environment variables), remove the double quotes around the connection string.
Keep it:
URL = mongodb+srv://..............

Answer (score -2):

Instead of all these solutions, what I did is just unplug my LAN cable and re-connected it and now it's working fine.