# Error in connecting node.js app to mongoDb Atlas database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

When I try to connect my node.js application with mongodb atlas where I have created a database named *test* I get the following error in console.

```
Error: queryTxt ETIMEOUT cluster0.z7ysr.mongodb.netat QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete]
```

I have a free tier atlas account.
I have used the mongoose library and the following code in my project.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://username:pwd@cluster0.z7ysr.mongodb.net/testretryWrites=true&w=majority'
{
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});
```

Comment: Hey @nikunjkr, just confirming, have you intentionally left the username:pwd as username:pwd or is it what you have not edited.

Comment: Hi! @AshutoshKumar I have just changed my original username and password to username and pwd respectively.

Comment: please show some more code.

Comment: Ok, Thanks 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61800062/error-querytxt-etimeout-when-connecting-to-mongodb-atlas-using-mongoose

Does it solve this.

Comment: See the anwer by @NithinKJoy, Comma seems to solve it

Answer (score 1):

Use ,(comma). You missed a comma after Mongo URI string.

```
let db='mongodb+srv://username:pwd@cluster0.z7ysr.mongodb.net/testretryWrites=true&w=majority'
//Used comma below.
mongoose.connect(db,{
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});
```

Comment: Ooh Great catch!!

Comment: O, ya missed it there. Thank you @NithinKJoy :)

Comment: welcome bro. :) Mark my answer as right so that my answer might help others too.

Comment: @nikunjkr, If this solves, Kindly mark it as Best Answer and then maybe Close the question.