# mongoose error `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I keep getting this MongoDB error, this is my connection to mongodb. I am trying to make a register and login application

```js
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

const uri = "mongodbconnection";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
client.connect(error => {
  const collection = client.db("test").collection("devices");
  // perform actions on the collection object
  client.close();
});
```

this is the signup application

```
router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
  //hashing the password
  const hashedPwd = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, saltRounds);
    //using passport-local for authentication
    const newUser = new User({
        email: req.body.email,
        password: hashedPwd
    })

    try {
        await newUser.save()
        console.log("new user created")
    } catch (error) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70254097/14389830 Check this.

Comment: thanks but it still isnt working, I set my ip to be allowed everywhere and still nothing

Comment: I think this may be your issue. https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/9732#issuecomment-751410546

Comment: @evan_tech1234 This usually happens to me when you try to connect to mongoose in some other file than the main app.js or whatever you execute. I would recommend using async/await along with mongoose to connect to your application without any issues.

Comment: @v1shva thanks so much this worked. After days this solved it.