# MongooseError: Operation `.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

As a getting-started project with express and MongoDB, I am creating a simple API that will return a joke. For that, I am making a way for users to send a POST request with the joke type and joke in the body which will add the joke to my cluster.

I am using the following Schema:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const schema = mongoose.Schema;

const jokecreateWay = new schema({

    JokeType: {
        type: String,
        //required: true
    },
    joke: {
        type: String,
        //required: true,
    },

})

module.exports = mongoose.model('joke', jokecreateWay)
```

with the following post-request code:

```
app.post('/add-joke', (req, res) => {
    const joke = req.body;
    const gType = req.body;

    const strigifiedJoke = JSON.stringify(joke);
    const strigifiedGType = JSON.stringify(gType);

    if (joke != null || gType != null) {
        try {

            const toBeInserted = JokeSchema.create({
                JokeType: strigifiedGType,
                joke: strigifiedJoke,
            });

            JokeSchema.save;
            return res.status(201).send({ message: 'joke added' });
        }
        catch (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({ message: err });
        }
    }
    else {
        res.status(418).send({ message: "You forgot to either specify the joke or its type." })
        return
    }

})
```

using insomnia to send the post request I get the following error in the console

```
D:\api\jokesAPIV2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:158
          const err = new MongooseError(message);
                      ^

MongooseError: Operation `jokes.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (D:\api\jokesAPIV2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-MongoDB-native\collection.js:158:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
```

Does anyone know why this happens and how I can fix it?

I have tried mostly everything suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65680842/error-mongooseerror-operation-users-insertone-buffering-timed-out-after-1?rq=1) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`create` returns a `Promise`. Also, make sure to destructure the `req.body` correctly:

```
app.post('/add-joke', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { joke, gType } = req.body;

    if (joke === '' || gType === '') {
      return res.status(418).send({
        message: 'You forgot to either specify the joke or its type.',
      });
    }

    const toBeInserted = await JokeSchema.create({
      JokeType: gType,
      joke: joke,
    });

    return res.status(201).send({ message: 'joke added' });
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(400).send({ message: err });
  }
});
```

Comment: With await, I get 400 - bad request error whereas without it, I get the original timeout error

Comment: @Satindar31 Can you post the result of `console.log(req.body)`?

Comment: `{ gType: 'dad', joke: 'this is the joke...' }`

Comment: @Satindar31 Try with edited answer

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `JokeSchema.save;` part since the `.create()` method will do everything. However, you have to add **await** before `.create()` method, and specify the function to be **async**.

```js
app.post('/add-joke', async (req, res) => {
  const { joke, gType } = req.body;

  // Validations
  if(!joke || !gType) {
    return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: 'One of the input is missing.' });
  }

  try {
    const joke = await JokeSchema.create({ JokeType: gType, joke });
    return res.status(200).send({ success: true, message: 'Joke successfully created.' });
  } catch(error) {
    return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: 'Error while adding joke.' });
  }
})
```