# Unable to connect to MongoDB Atlas Cluster from Mongosh terminal

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to connect to the Mongo Atlas Cluster through the Mongosh terminal using `mongosh "mongodb+srv://cluster0.sdwcf.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase" --username <username>`. But I am unable to connect the error being `Error: queryTxt ETIMEOUT cluster0.sdwcf.mongodb.net`. I found the same issue at https://github.com/metabase/metabase/issues/9867 but issue has been closed without any solution.

One the other hand if I try to connect using the mongo 3.4 or earlier command `mongo "mongodb://cluster0-shard-00-00.sdwcf.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01.sdwcf.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02.sdwcf.mongodb.net:27017/myFirstDatabase?replicaSet=atlas-10n7hz-shard-0" --ssl --authenticationDatabase admin --username <username> --password <password>` it works just fine. But given that the Mongosh terminal has superseded the Mongo terminal, I would really like to know if there is any fix for this..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: queryTxt ETIMEOUT when connecting to MongoDb Atlas using mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61800062/error-querytxt-etimeout-when-connecting-to-mongodb-atlas-using-mongoose)

Comment: @SaravanakrishnanPk As in the article you suggested and the same in my question, I did try going for older version Mongo shell commands which did work. But since the Mongosh has superseded the Mongo terminal, I am looking to somehow make the Mongosh shell command work.

Comment: did you tried with `8.8.8.8` as DNS?

Comment: Try using the `mongodb://` URL with mongosh.