# Mongodb atlas connection failed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I have created a database named priceDatabase in mongodb atlas. Also I have created a user with usename 'admin' and password 'admin'. I am trying to connect to my node js application to the mongodb atlas. For this I am using mongoose.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)
  .then((db) => {
    console.log("Connected to the mongodb server successfuly: ");
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

.env file

```
MONGO_URI = mongodb+srv://admin:admin@pricedatabase.re29j.mongodb.net/priceDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Now if I run the code I am getting error as

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (B:\projects\priceTagServer\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:797:32)
    at B:\projects\priceTagServer\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:341:10
    at B:\projects\priceTagServer\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (B:\projects\priceTagServer\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (B:\projects\priceTagServer\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1167:10)    
    at Mongoose.connect (B:\projects\priceTagServer\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:340:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (B:\projects\priceTagServer\models\db.js:10:4)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
      'pricedatabase-shard-00-01.re29j.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'pricedatabase-shard-00-02.re29j.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'pricedatabase-shard-00-00.re29j.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'atlas-bew5c1-shard-0',
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
  }
}
```

It is saying my is not whitelisted in the mongodb atlas but I have given network access to 0.0.0.0/0 which means every device can have access to the database. Then, why I am still getting that error? Am I missing something?

Comment: did you try something like `.connect(URI,{useUnifiedTopology: true,useNewUrlParser: true})`

Comment: Now I am getting "MongoParseError: option useunifiedtopogy is not supported" error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70434844/error-querytxt-etimeout-cluster0-dxzhf-mongodb-net/70435021#70435021

Comment: You can try to add your IP and to make a test. Try to access throw the Compass to certificate.